# Change input type value if is mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Guys I'm using jquery UI library for date picking and time picker addon. 
All work on PC but I want to change `input type` from `text` to `date` or `time`.

When I test on mobile device I want mobile to use default datetime picker(scroller).

By default I just use simple code for showing dialogs

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
$('.timepicker').timepicker();
```

So is it possible to check if it is a mobile device? If yes change type to date or time.

I try to create function which will detect if a user connect with mobile device but it doesn't work

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
      var date = document.getElementById('datepicker');
      date.setAttribute('type','date');
}
```

But this function work when I check if it is mobile

```
function isMobile() { return ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement); }
```

**Here is full working code:**

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var date = $(".datepicker");
        var time = $(".timepicker");
        var isTouchDevice = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;

         if ( isTouchDevice ) {
             date.attr("type", "date");
             time.attr("type", "time");

        } else {
             date.attr("type", "text");
             $('.datepicker').datepicker();
             $('.timepicker').timepicker();
        }

    })();

</script>
```

Comment: Also, it's a bit redundant to declare the isMobile() function because the var that I declared (isTouchDevice) will already return true on mobile and false on non-mobile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check for all touch devices like this:

```
var isTouchDevice = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
if ( isTouchDevice ) {
  // do mobile handling
  var date = $('.datepicker');
  date.attr('type','date');
} else {
  // do default handling
}
```

Comment: in the some time u post ansver and me new update.. Check it... I try this and my update, input type is not changed its again `type=text`

Comment: Try my updated answer with the jQuery $('.datepicker') selector. The problem is, you were trying to fetch "datepicker" by the id "datepicker" but "datepicker" is a CLASS not an ID. The period (.) denotes classes, the pound sign (#) denotes IDs. Also, if you could go to https://jsfiddle.net and create an example of your problem, it would be much easier for others to learn from as well.